# How I use Bar Code reader and QR Reader?(Titanium 2.0.2.GA)

Tags: android, iphone, titanium

I want use [this](https://github.com/mwaylabs/titanium-barcode) [1](https://github.com/mwaylabs/titanium-barcode) for using Bar code or QR code scanner. I am using Titanium 2.0.2.GA. but i got an error message. This is not support for 2.0.2.GA Titanium SDK. or this module is not found.
How I remove this problem?
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That module is only for Android. The one you want for iPhone is http://code.google.com/p/tibar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the module locally into the project or as a global Titanium module? Also, have you included the module in your tiapp.xml file? If not, that might be the problem.